# Adding view does not update layout_weight

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

I am having an issue in my application. I have a TableLayout, with a set space and I want the rows to evenly take up the full space. This works with the TableRows I inserted in the XML, however, if I want to add a TableRow later on, it takes up the minimal height.

Here I add the TableRow to my TableLayout:

```
 tl = findViewById(R.id.tabelle);
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tablerow, null);
 tl.addView(view);
```

And this is the XML of the TableRow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
style="@style/tr_style">
    <TextView
        style="@style/tv_style"
        android:text="@string/spieler1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pkt_spieler1"
        style="@style/tv_style" />
</TableRow>
```

The `TableLayout` on starting the activity
[image]

The `TableLayout` after adding a row
[image]

Comment: try to call `t1..invalidate()` or `t1.postInvalidate()`

Comment: @ADM Doesn't seem to be a duplicate. Reference is about adding row, this question is about evenly distributing the rows when one is added programmatically.

Comment: Ok . seems duplicate in first glance .Thx'

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `android:layout_height="0dp"` in the xml?